# how to exclude certain columns from calculation at each point

Tags: javascript, r, mean

I have a data set of previous 3 month average stock returns of 200 firms for 92 months. Months are in rows and firms are in columns. Now i have to calculate mean of the top 20 percent of firms given that the values are non-zero. Following is the code:

```
mmt1<-mean(as.numeric(comb[1,1:40]))
```

I need to know how to exclude zero values from mean calculation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
mmt1<-mean(as.numeric(comb[, which(colSums(comb)!=0)]))
```